# BIGQUERY Error --> SELECT list expression references column FY which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:20]

Tags: google-bigquery

I am facing this error "SELECT list expression references column FY which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:20]" This is the SQL sentence:

```
SELECT '00-ActualTotalRevenues' as type,code, previous_code,
     name as master1,'' as master2,'' as master3,'' as master4,'' as master5,
case when FY < 2018 then sum(January+February+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November+December) else 0 end as detail,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(January) else 0 end as detail1,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(February) else 0 end as detail2,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(March) else 0 end as detail3,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(April) else 0 end as detail4,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(May) else 0 end as detail5,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(June) else 0 end as detail6,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(July) else 0 end as detail7,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(August) else 0 end as detail8,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(September) else 0 end as detail9,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(October) else 0 end as detail10,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(November) else 0 end as detail11,
     case when FY = 2018 then sum(December) else 0 end as detail12 
FROM `basetis-etl-bigquery.services.results_actual_revenues_complete` where FY <= 2018
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

The following query runs without issues:

```
SELECT '00-ActualTotalRevenues' as type,code, previous_code,
     name as master1,'' as master2,'' as master3,'' as master4,'' as master5,
sum(January) as detail1,
sum(February) as detail2,
sum(March) as detail3,
sum(April) as detail4,
sum(May) as detail5,
sum(June) as detail6,
sum(July) as detail7,
sum(August) as detail8,
sum(September) as detail9,
sum(October) as detail10,
sum(November) as detail11,
sum(December) as detail12 
FROM `basetis-etl-bigquery.services.results_actual_revenues_complete` where FY <= 2018
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Thank you in advance for your support.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below instead

```
#standardSQL
SELECT '00-ActualTotalRevenues' AS type, code, previous_code,
  name AS master1,'' AS master2,'' AS master3,'' AS master4,'' AS master5,
  SUM(IF(FY < 2018, January+February+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November+December, 0))AS detail,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, January, 0)) AS detail1,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, February, 0)) AS detail2,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, March, 0)) AS detail3,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, April, 0)) AS detail4,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, May, 0)) AS detail5,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, June, 0)) AS detail6,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, July, 0)) AS detail7,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, August, 0)) AS detail8,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, September, 0)) AS detail9,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, October, 0)) AS detail10,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, November, 0)) AS detail11,
  SUM(IF(FY = 2018, December, 0)) AS detail12 
FROM `basetis-etl-bigquery.services.results_actual_revenues_complete` WHERE FY <= 2018
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```